# Dart how to call the same function when it ends*?

Tags: loops, dart

I have a list of [File](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/File-class.html)s that need to be uploaded to a server. The upload function has a callback that indicates when the upload is complete. How can I upload each file in a list sequentially until all files have been uploaded?

```
//My file list: 
List<File> _list;
//The upload function accepts a single File and has an onComplete function
upload(_list.first, (){
   //Now I need to trigger an upload of the second file in the list and so on until all tasks have been uploaded. 
});
```

How can I get the files to upload sequentially?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```dart
void uploadAll(List<File> files) {
  int cursor = 0;
  void uploadNext() {
    if (cursor == values.length) return;
    upload(values[cursor++], uploadNext);
  }
  uploadNext();
}
```